# Interaction of 3d objects in 4d space in Unity

Tags: object, unity-game-engine, 3d, 4d

I have an idea for the realization of Hogwarts fic "Harry Potter and the Methods of Rationality". This is not explicitly mentioned, but by describing the possibility of imposing space and the absence of a visible difference in the direction and length between the leads leading to different places, one can understand that Hogwarts is in a pseudo-4D space created using magic. But I came across a problem: I do not know how to make interaction between 3D objects in Unity, but in 4D space.
The figure depicts 2D characters in a pseudo 3D space (This is 2D layers), when they go into one of the passes they do not notice the height changes the way, because they see in 2D. If one of the characters looks from a height 0.5 to a height 1 or 0, he will see what is there, because the difference in height is not enough, but if he looks from a height 0 to a height 1, he can't see what is there (too high). The same thing happens in the pseudo-4D space of Hogwarts, but only the corridors do not change the height, but change the w coordinate, and as we are 3D creatures, we will not see this change.

You can see image there:

[image: img]

The height in the image can vary from 0 to one, it is displayed with color from black to white.

Comment: You'll need to fake 4d by swapping segments of 3D space when the user is not looking

Comment: That or program [Miegakure](http://miegakure.com) from scratch.

Comment: @zambari Thanks, but I'm afraid this does not suit me, because of the possibility to leave objects with physics in a certain place, and this is the main problem.

Comment: @Draco18s It's too long and too expensive, besides, I'm not going to reinvent the wheel. And I do not want to re-create Miegakure, I want to make a pseudo 4D moving it along a shallow slope, only on w coordinate.

Comment: You're still going to need to find a way to handle the 4D transform yourself, whether you're faking it, or you're doing all the true, accurate math. And one of the problem is, when an object moves out of 3D space along `w`, [*weird shit* happens](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0t4aKJuKP0Q) (and rotations make it worse, and oh yeah, if you thought Quaternions were difficult, try dealing with Octonions).

Comment: Any vertex displacement shader with a nice moving noise texture will be artistically much more controllable than most math

Comment: I do not use Unity but maybe this [how should i handle (morphing) 4D objects in opengl?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44970550/2521214) might help a bit especially look at the 4D rotations link. You need to create 5x5 homogenous transform matrices similar to [4x4 homogenous transform matrices](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28084380/2521214)