# Drawing Line using matrix OpenGL

Tags: opengl, glsl, shader

I'm working on this shaders that I modified 
but I wish to simply draw a line instead of this blur / bloom effect
I understood that is the Float d that is used as a modifier but how to get this simple line instead

I based my research on this [shader](http://glslsandbox.com/e#50194.0)

Will appreciate any help

Zoltan

```c
#ifdef GL_ES
precision mediump float;
#endif

mat4 mat  = mat4 (
        vec4 ( Scale * SizeTpDwn , 0.0 , 0.0 , 0.0 ),
        vec4 ( 0.0 , Scale * SizeLftRght , 0.0 , 0.0 ),
        vec4 ( 0.0 , 0.0 , Scale , 0.0 ),
        vec4 ( 0.0 , 0.0 , 0.0 , Scale ) );

vec2 pos;
vec4 linecol = vec4 (0.5 , 0.5 , 0.7 , 0.5);

vec4 col = vec4 ( 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0 );

void Line4 ( vec4 a, vec4 b );
void Line2 ( vec2 a, vec2 b );

void main( void ) {

    pos = gl_FragCoord.xy / RENDERSIZE.xy;
    pos -= .5;

    //Line
    Line4 ( vec4 ( LengthTX, MoveTX, .2 ,-.2), vec4 (LengthTX2, MoveTX2, .2, -.2 ) );
    //Line4 ( vec4 ( MoveRX, LengthRY, .2 ,-.2 ),vec4 ( MoveRX2,LengthRY2, .2, -.2 ) );
    //Line4 ( vec4 (MoveLX, LengthLY, .2 ,-.2 ),vec4 (MoveLX2,LengthLY2, .2, -.2 ) );
    //Line4 ( vec4 ( LengthDX,MoveDX, .2 ,-.2), vec4 (LengthDX2,MoveDX2, .2, -.2 ) );

    gl_FragColor = vec4( col.xyz, 1.0 );
}

void Line4 ( vec4 a, vec4 b )
{
    a = mat * a;
    //a.xyz /= 1.5 + a.w * 2.;
    b = mat * b;
    //b.xyz /= 1.5 + b.w * 2.;
    Line2 ( a.xy , b.xy );
}

void Line2 ( vec2 a, vec2 b )
{
    float dtc = (distance ( pos , a ) + distance ( pos , b ) - distance ( a , b )); //+ 1e-5);

    //linecol = vec4 (0.5 , 0.5 , 0.7 , 0.5);
    col += max ( 1. - pow ( dtc * 14. , 0.10 ) , -.10 );
}
```

Comment: and how should we know what to do with uncomented undescribed foreighn code without any description what is input .... and what exactly you want as output. I assume you are renderig some QUAD covering area of your line so in fragment you need to compute perpendicular distance to your line and if bigger than half of line thickness `discard` it otherwise output its color...  How is your line defined?  what is the meaning of the functions and variables? no one will reverse engineer analyze your code  as it si way much more work than implementing this from scratch. So +Close for now

Comment: sorry I'm a beginner I don't know every habits of programmation community.
This code is a Interactive Shader Format based on OpenGL.  
The line defined use the mat4 (matrix)

Comment: That is nice but what is the meaning of the matrix line is usually set as 2 endpoints in graphics or a start point and direction/delta vector. Matrices are usually used with multiplication by vector so what should be the vector  format? I expect some parametrization parameter like `t` ... without the background knowledge of what and how you does things we can only guess. Also I do not see  any data passing so your line is hardcoded?

Comment: My comments are not about habits. You just throw at us code we know nothing about. You wrote it so you know what part is for what purpose and what variable means what. But we do not know any of this ...  so if you really want to help with this you need to add some description for us. Otherwise we can only trow at you entirely different code which we are familiar with... but that can have different api and or configuration or constraints than you want ...

Comment: I based my research on this shaders : http://glslsandbox.com/e#50194.0
I wanted to understood how it works so I deleted a lot of function to keep at this a simple rectangle and now a simple line 
What I understood is that "Line4" is drawing the point and "Line2" using a vec2 give the line the colors using the "d" function

Comment: Well finally some small reference at least. I retracted the Close Vote. You should add the info from your last comment into your question (Not all the people read all the comments). btw from quick look at the link it looks like 4D tesseract ... if the case that might shine some small light on the matrix usage (used to convert from 4D into 2D preview even if it should be 5x5) see [how should i handle (morphing) 4D objects in opengl?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44970550/2521214)

Comment: Added ! 
thank your patience

Comment: just a silly question you want this for 4D perspective lines? or cross section with XYZ hyperplane or just 3D or 2D and that shader was the only one you found ... ?

Comment: it was just a way to understand matrix and drawing line. one more step in learning OpenGL !

Comment: well the use of matrix in 4D rendering is quite a bit different than standard 3D rendering ... hence the confusion as the matrix has nothing to do with the line of yours ... If you want to understand matrices I think you should take a look at this [Understanding 4x4 homogenous transform matrices](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28084380/2521214) and the sublinks there.

Comment: Thank you for the link !
seems a bit complex at this time but after 2 or 3 Time reading it hope to understand it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have to do is to find the closest distance of the current fragment to the line. If this distance is smaller than the half line thickness, then the fragment is on the line.
To create a line with sharp edges, I recommend to use the [`step`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/step.xhtml) function, which returns 0.0, if a value is smaller than a reference value and 1.0 otherwise.
Th draw a line which is not endless, you have to check if the point on the endless line, which is closest to the current position, is in between the start and the end of the line:

```
void Line2 (vec2 L1, vec2 L2)
{
    vec2  P   = pos;
    vec2  O   = L1;         
    vec2  D   = normalize(L2-L1);
    float d   = dot(P-O, D);
    vec2  X   = L1 + D * d;

    float dtc;
    if (d < 0.0)
        dtc = distance(L1, P); // d < 0.0 -> X is "before" L1
    else if (d > distance(L1, L2))
        dtc = distance(L2, P); // d > distance(L1, L2) -> X is "after" L2
    else
        dtc = distance(pos, X);

    col += 1.0 - step(0.01, dtc);
}
```

Preview

[image: line]

---

Explanation:

Lets assume, that the line is defined by a Point `O` and a [Unit vector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_vector) `D` with gives the direction of the line. Note the length of a unit vector is 1.

Further you have the point `P` and you want to find the closest point `X` on the line (`O`, `D`) to `P`.

First calculate a vector `V` from `O` to `P`:

```
V = P - O;
```

The distance `d` from `O` to the intersection point `X` can be calculated by the [Dot product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product).
 Note, since `D` is a unit vector, the dot prduct of `V` and `D` is equal the cosine of the angle between the line (`O`, `D`) and the vector `V`, multiplied by the amount (length) of `V`:

```
d = dot(V, D);
```

The intersection point `X`, can be calculated by shifting the point `O` along the line (`D`) by the distance `d`:

```
X = O + D * d;
```

So the formula for the intersection point is:

```
O ... any point on the line
D ... unit vector which points in the direction of the line
P ... the "Point"

X = O + D * dot(P-O, D);
```

[image]

Note, if the line is defined by 2 points, `L1` and `L2` then the unit vector `D` can be calcualted as follows:

```
D = normalize(L2-L1);
```

Comment: Oh thank you for your answer. I'm going to scratch my head on it to understand everything but sure It's going to help ! 
Keep you in touch

Comment: it works perfectly ! 
I was stuck since one week on it ! Thank you so much 
Now I have to understand it :)

Comment: Done 
Yes I understood that there was a threshold using distance but could not find the solution as I'm a newbie in programmation ^^

Comment: @ I tried to add some more explanations to the answer. I think the key to understand the solution is the sketch at the end of the answer an he understanding of the [`Dot product`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product).