# Find analytic solution to this system of quadratic equations

Tags: math, equation-solving

I have reduced my problem to this system of 3 quadratic equations:

```
  (k1*x + k2*y + k4)^2 = k7      
  (k2*y + k3*z + k5)^2 = k8      
  (k3*z + k1*x + k6)^2 = k9

  (Solve for x, y, z, k1..k9 are constants)
```

I have spent quite some time not finding an analytical solution. Can someone give me the solution?

P.S. There are some relations between the constants that may simplify the problem. I can post them if needed tomorrow.

Thx Peter

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. How is this a programming problem? If you add more context, including evidence of your work so far on the problem and a statement of just where you are stuck, this problem would be a better fit for the [Mathematics Stack Exchange](http://math.stackexchange.com/) site.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about practical computer programming but rather belongs on [Mathematics Stack Exchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/) once the questioner has added more of his own work and explained just where he is stuck.

Comment: I agree that it should be on Math Exchange. However, here's the solution: Take the square root of k7, k8, and k9 to obtain a system of linear equations. Since the square root can be positive or negative, you need to solve the system for all 8 combinations of signs (±sqrt(k7), ±sqrt(k8), ±sqrt(k9)). You will obtain up to 8 real-valued answers or exactly 8 answers if you accept complex coefficients.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pure math but solvable by programig,... first use the Gilles-Philippe Paillé comment and separate variables:

```
(k1*x + k2*y + k4)^2 = k7
(k2*y + k3*z + k5)^2 = k8
(k3*z + k1*x + k6)^2 = k9
-------------------------
k1*x + k2*y + k4 = sqrt(k7)
k2*y + k3*z + k5 = sqrt(k8)
k3*z + k1*x + k6 = sqrt(k9)
-------------------------
k1*x + k2*y = sqrt(k7) - k4
k2*y + k3*z = sqrt(k8) - k5
k3*z + k1*x = sqrt(k9) - k6
-------------------------
k1*x + k2*y +  0*z = sqrt(k7) - k4
 0*x + k2*y + k3*z = sqrt(k8) - k5
k1*x +  0*y + k3*z = sqrt(k9) - k6
-------------------------
```

Now you can rewrite to matrix form

```
    | k1 k2  0 |
A = |  0 k2 k3 |
    | k1  0 k3 |

    | x |
B = | y |
    | z |

    | sqrt(k7) - k4 |
C = | sqrt(k8) - k5 |
    | sqrt(k9) - k6 |


             A * B =              C
Inverse(A) * A * B = Inverse(A) * C
                 B = Inverse(A) * C
```

So its simple Inverse of 3x3 matrix. If you expand it to 4x4 by zeor padding and adding 1 to diagonal You can use 4x4 matrix inverse like this:

- [Understanding 4x4 homogenous transform matrices](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28084380/2521214)

Just look for `matrix_inv` in the C++ code example. You can find also the multiplication of matrix and vector there too `matrix_mul_vector`...

The code would in C++ look like this:

```cpp
double A[16]=
 {
 k1, 0,k1, 0,
 k2,k2, 0, 0,
  0,k3,k3, 0,
  0, 0, 0, 1
 };
double B[4],C[4]=
 {
 sqrt(k7) - k4,
 sqrt(k8) - k5,
 sqrt(k9) - k6
 };

matrix_inv(A,A);
matrix_mul(B,A,C);
```

now `B` should hold your resulting `x,y,z` values if your equation has solution. What is left is just to add sign combinations as the `sqrt` of the system loss it ... In case all constants and variables are non negative you can forget about this and use the result directly without trying the 8 combinations ...

If I see it right the combinations are done like this

```cpp
double C[4]=
 {
 (+/-)sqrt(k7) - k4,
 (+/-)sqrt(k8) - k5,
 (+/-)sqrt(k9) - k6
 };
```

so for each of the 8 `C` combinations compute the result ... The combinations itself can be done by a for cycle using 3 lowest bits of iterator variable to decide the sign like:

```cpp
matrix_inv(A,A);
for (int i=0;i<8;i++)
 {
 if ((i&1)==0) C[0]=+sqrt(k7)-k4; else C[0]=-sqrt(k7)-k4;
 if ((i&2)==0) C[1]=+sqrt(k8)-k5; else C[1]=-sqrt(k8)-k5;
 if ((i&4)==0) C[2]=+sqrt(k9)-k6; else C[2]=-sqrt(k9)-k6;
 matrix_mul(B,A,C);
 // here B holds the i-th solution
 }
```

In case of complex domain just change the `double` with a complex data-type...

Comment: Thx alot, i did not take the squareroot and got stuck with many ±sqrt-terms when solving one equation for x. I did not see that you could do the ± permutations as last step. Thx to Gilles-Philippe Paillé too.

Comment: @PeterPohl its not the last step as you multiply by inverse matrix of A from left after the combination of `+/-` but I got your point :)

Comment: @Spektre Thanks for the detailed answer! I noted a small mistake in the line `Inverse(A) * B = Inverse(A) * C`. It should be `Inverse(A) * A * B = Inverse(A) * C`. Also, I think that using the 4x4 inverse is a bit overkill for this task. I understand that it is to reuse existing code, but the performance can be greatly affected.

Comment: @Gilles-PhilippePaillé Nice catch thx I repaired it. Yes 4x4 is slower but not that much. I have also 3x3 somewhere but too lazy to search for it and that 4x4 is already posted. btw I use this [full pseudo inverse matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42293434/2521214) for orthonormal matrices which is much much faster but not usable in this case ... as the ortho-normality is not granted. Here are [GEM and Determinant based inverses](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55439139/2521214) for general case and I also got N-Dimensional matrix/vector template there ...

Comment: @Gilles-PhilippePaillé btw that last template was a written as a core math for mine 4D engine related to this QA: [how should i handle (morphing) 4D objects in opengl?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44970550/2521214)