# How to find the hyper-volume of the 4d analogue of a parallelepiped?

Tags: math, geometry, linear-algebra, 4d

Firstly, does said analogue exist?

Secondly, how to find its 4d-volume/hyper-volume given 4 vectors for sides, ideally using dot, cross product, etc.

Thirdly, what would be the 3D analogue to surface area? Eg. 1D-Arc length, 2D-Surface area, 3D- Volume, 4D-?

Comment: see [ND vector and square matrix math template](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55439139/2521214) for the cross product computation (its already implemented) as the answer suggest  hypervolume is just size of result of the cross product of all basis vectors of the hyper parallelogram.  this might interest you too: [mine 4D rendering engine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44970550/2521214)

Comment: Good question, and a complete answer has already been given, but for the record this question is really more suitable for math.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you are describing is generalized using the determinant.

**nD object embedded in an nD space**

For objects using all dimensions, e.g., a parallelogram in 2D or a parallelepiped in 3D, put the `n` vectors defining the sides of the (hyper-)parallelepiped as rows of a matrix and compute the determinant:

```
2D       3D          4D             5D
|x1 y1|  |x1 y1 z1|  |x1 y1 z1 w1|  (Repeat the same pattern)
|x1 y2|  |x2 y2 z2|  |x2 y2 z2 w2|
         |x3 y3 z3|  |x3 y3 z3 w3|
                     |x4 y4 z4 w4|
```

Note that the obtained (hyper-)volume is signed, depending on the orientation of the vectors. It is thus possible to have negative volumes.

**(n-1)D object embedded in nD space**

For objects using one dimension less than the space in which they live, e.g., a parallelogram in 3D space, you can use the cross-product (which derives from the determinant) or a generalization of the cross-product. For example, The area of a parallelogram embedded in 3D defined by two 3D vector `(x1,y1,z1)` and `(x2,y2,z2)` is calculated from matrix containing the two vectors as rows:

```
[x1 y1 z1]
[x2 y2 z2]
```

From this matrix, simply create all combinations of 2x2 sub-matrix, calculate the determinant of each matrix, and put them in a vector as such

```
[|y1 z1|, |z1 x1|, |x1 y1|] = (y1*z2-z1*y1, z1*x2-x1*z2, x1*y2-y1*x2)
[|y2 z2|  |z2 x2|  |x2 y2|]
```

You obtain a vector, and the length of this vector is the area of the parallelogram: `sqrt((y1*z2-z1*y1)^2 + (z1*x2-x1*z2)^2 + (x1*y2-y1*x2)^2)`.

**The (Almost-)Ultimate Generalization**

From this last example, we can create a general recipe that works for any object embedded in any dimension (yes, you can calculate the volume of a 3D parallelepiped embedded in a 17D space):

1. Put all vectors describing the object as rows of a (possibly non-square) matrix.
2. Enumerate all possible combinations of square sub-matrices.
3. Calculate the determinant of all these sub-matrices and put them in a list (the order is not important if all you want is the volume).
4. Square these determinants individually.
5. Sum them all.
6. Take the square root of the result.

Note that this last recipe gives the unsigned volume since you square then take the square-root.

Final note: Obviously, this answer is more of a recipe than an explanation of *why* all these calculations work. For more information on this subject, I suggest you to look into [Exterior Algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exterior_algebra), which is a formalism that uses the *wedge product* (a generalization of the cross-product) to define these hyper-volumes in a very general way.