# When to overload an operator in C++ as a member of a user-defined data structure and when not? I am completely lost

Tags: c++, math, vector-graphics

For any of you who can help explain to me when and when not to overload an operator as a member of a class or struct for example or not as a member, like global one.

The thing is that I am learning all about vectors and 3D vectors etc for mathematical learning purposes and trying to simulate the common operations on them to better understand their behaviour when doing so.

So, I bought a book which lightly touches on the same aspect as I do but I got to the part of it where the author of the book have written a simple vector struct in C++ and got bunch of overloaded operators that some where declared and defined inside the struct and some weren't.

Let me give you this exact example that left me completely baffled. The following example will show two different overloaded operators by which the two of them do the same "overall" purpose (I think?)  which is (vector/scalar multiplication), however, one is being a member of the struct and the other isn't.

```
struct Vector3D
{
    float x, y, z;

    Vector3D() = default;

    Vector3D(float a, float b, float c)
    {
        x = a;
        y = b;
        z = c;
    }

    Vector3D& operator*=(float s)
    {
        x *= s;
        y *= y;
        z *= z;

        return(*this);
    }

    Vector3D& operator/=(float s)
    {
        s = 1.0f / s;

        x *= s;
        y *= s;
        z *= s;

        return(*this);
    }

    float& operator[](int i)
    {
        return ((&x)[i]);
    }

    const float& operator[](int i) const
    {
        return ((&x)[i]);
    }
};


inline Vector3D operator*(const Vector3D& v, float s)
{
  return (Vector3D(v.x * s, v.y * s, v.z * s));
}
```

The one that I am specifically asking about is the

```
  Vector3D& operator*=(float s)
    {
        x *= s;
        y *= s;
        z *= s;

        return(*this);
    }
```

And

```
inline Vector3D operator*(const Vector3D& v, float s)
{
  return (Vector3D(v.x * s, v.y * s, v.z * s));
}
```

Please if anyone has a clear explanation to share it

I have of course tried the above code to see what difference they make and I have found couple of things where they differ:

is when I try to print out to the screen the final result of multiplying a vector with a scalar (any float number) using both methods, only the member overloaded operator will printed out right away. The one that outside the struct can not be printed out unless the return got assigned to another vector instance.

For example:

```
int main()
{

    float s = 2; //Defining the scalar

    // Invoking the first overloaded operator

    Vector3D vecA(2, 2, 2);

    vecA *= 3;

    for(int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
    {
        std::cout << vecA[i] << std::endl; // 6, 6, 6 (Worked)
    }

    // Now Invoking the global overloaded operator

    Vector3D vecB(2, 2, 2);

    vecB * s; 

    for(int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
    {
        std::cout << vecB[i] << std::endl; // 2, 2, 2 (No change)
    }
    
}
```

Comment: `vecB * s; ` create a new `Vector3D` and then discards it - it does not modify `vecB` in any way

Comment: Do you understand the difference between `*` and `*=` in C++, what they do and how they're different? Forget about classes, but how these two operators work on ordinary `int`s, for example?

Comment: @UnholySheep So what is the purpose of having the other overloaded operator? I mean if the first one is already doing the job, then why having the second one? And this seems to be the common practice across many textbooks and online tutorials.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I know that *= is doing the arithmetic operation plus reassign the new value to the same variable again as a syntactically sugar way. Like instead of having to write vecB = vecB * s;  I don't know if there's anything else to be honest with you.

Comment: @pk6x - They do *different* jobs. That is the point! :-) `vecA *= 3` modifies `vecA`, while `vecC = vecB * 3;` creates a new value *without* changing the original. With ordinary numbers you want to compute `2 + 2` without changing any of the 2's. Vectors work the same.

Comment: @BoP, so what dictate to have one of them to be as a member and one not? Or does it even matter? For example, having all overloaded operators that I wish to have not being as members and defined as global ones, would that be something I am not suppose to do?

Comment: @pb6x - Most of them are not "dictated" at all. A few, like assignment and indexing *must* be members, but most of the others can be either. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators  So no help from the language - you have to choose yourself.  :-)

Comment: I have serious reservations about the quality of the book you're using. For one thing, `operator*(const Vector3D& v, float s)` should use `*=` rather than write the same code a second time: `Vector3D result = v; v *= s; return v;`. And, second, in that `operator[]`, `((&x)[i])` pretends that `x` is the first element of an array. It's not. The code is not required to do anything sensible; it might "work" by accident, but with a different compiler (including the same compiler with different build switches) it could produce nonsense. Or worse; the behavior is undefined.

Comment: @BoP great! Now I'll remain silent until the day comes when I would think that I have got it :-/ Thanks anyway yours helped a lot.

Comment: @PeteBecker Honestly I myself not entirely sure if this book is the right one or not, I think I just went with it and here I am not able to pass the page 10 after dayyys went by. The one I am doing right now called Foundations of Game Engine Development, Mathematics Volume 1, and I think it is was one of very few textbooks talking about the math is involved in writing an engine. If you got any better options please share them as I am really interested in this kind of books.

Comment: @pk6x -- I don't have recommendations. If you're after the mathematics and the book is strong there, you could stick with it and supplement it with something less math oriented and more C++ish. You might start looking [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: 1. `struct` and `class` is more or less the  same thing in C++. 2. as the @tbxfreeware answer says its about comutatibility of operands beware it also depends on compilers each has its own quirks that had to be tweaked to its liking... 3. take a look at these: [GLSL_math.h](https://ulozto.net/tamhle/Lac6wsTA65Ni#!ZJD0MwR2AJR0ZmR5LJAyZwHlLJH1MJyBAGL0I3MvJKDlF2L3LD==) , [ND vector and matrix math template](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55439139/2521214) if you are going for 3D gfx also see [Understanding 4x4 homogenous transform matrices](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28084380/2521214)

Comment: @PeteBecker I have decided to finish it and see the overall gain from it, hopefully it wont mess things up for me to the worse :P. Thanx for the suggestions.

Comment: @Spektre Thanks for the suggested materials I will definitely going to have a look at them very soon!

Answer (score 1):

One reason to choose a non-member operator is symmetry. By symmetry, I mean that certain operators should be commutative.

Scalar multiplication is a good example. It is reasonable to want both `(s * vec)` and `(vec * s)` to be allowable expressions. If you want to use `s` as the left operand, however, you must use a non-member function. You cannot use a member function, because `s` is not a `Vector3D` object. In fact, you must define two `operator*` functions, one for `(s * vec)`, and the other for `(vec * s)`.

Stream operators are another time when you must use non-member operator functions, because the left operand is not a Vector3D object.

The comments in the following program explain further. It contains several idioms you may find useful, including the *hidden friend* idiom. In addition, the program fixes the two problems identified by @Pete Becker:

1. `operator*` should be implemented by invoking `operator*=`. Coding the same set of operations in two different functions is error-prone. Sooner or later, the two will get out of sync!
2. The `operator[]` functions in the OP invoke undefined behavior, because they make the unwarranted assumption that member variables `x`, `y`, and `z` are stored as if they were the elements of an array. The code below uses an *actual* array.

```cpp
// main.cpp
#include <array>
#include <cstddef>
#include <format>
#include <iostream>

class Vector3D
{
    enum : std::size_t { zero, one, two, three };
    using value_type = double;
    std::array<value_type, three> v{};
public:
    value_type& x() noexcept { return v[zero]; }
    value_type& y() noexcept { return v[one]; }
    value_type& z() noexcept { return v[two]; }

    value_type const& x() const noexcept { return v[zero]; }
    value_type const& y() const noexcept { return v[one]; }
    value_type const& z() const noexcept { return v[two]; }

    Vector3D() noexcept
        = default;
    Vector3D(
        value_type const x,
        value_type const y,
        value_type const z) noexcept
    {
        this->x() = x;
        this->y() = y;
        this->z() = z;
    }
    Vector3D& operator*=(value_type const s) noexcept
    {
        // operator*= must be a member function.
        x() *= s;
        y() *= s;
        z() *= s;
        return *this;
    }
    friend Vector3D operator*(Vector3D v, value_type const s) noexcept
    {
        // Note that v is a value parameter that receives 
        // a copy of its argument. Changing v here, will not 
        // change the original argument used when operator* 
        // is invoked.
        //
        // This function could also be implemented as a 
        // member function (with only one parameter, s).
        //
        // It is a common idiom for operator* to be implemented 
        // by calling member function operator*= to do the work.
        // 
        // The following return statement can be broken into pieces:
        // 
        //    1. Parameter v is like a "local" variable. It is a 
        //       Vector3D object, but it is not *this object.
        //
        //    2. Because v is a Vector3D object, we can use 
        //       operator*= to perform scalar multiplication on it.
        //
        //    3. operator*= returns a reference to v, which now 
        //       holds the result of scalar multiplication.
        //
        //    4. The return statement copies the result, and 
        //       sends it back to the calling routine.
        return v *= s;
    }
    friend Vector3D operator*(value_type const s, Vector3D v) noexcept
    {
        // In order to have a symmetric operator*, where s 
        // can appear either first or second, we have to code 
        // a second version of operator*.
        //
        // This function cannot be a member function, because 
        // the first operand, s, is not an object!
        //
        // Note that the two operator* functions use the 
        // "hidden friend" idiom.
        return v *= s;
    }
    Vector3D& operator+=(Vector3D const& that) noexcept
    {
        // operator+= must be a member function.
        x() += that.x();
        y() += that.y();
        z() += that.z();
        return *this;
    }
    friend Vector3D operator+(Vector3D a, Vector3D const& b)
    {
        // operator+ can be implemented either as a 
        // member function (with one parameter), or as 
        // a non-member function (with two parameters).
        //
        // I have chosen to use a non-member function, 
        // so that I can treat the left operand as 
        // a "local" variable.
        //
        // Note that parameter `a` is a value parameter.
        // It receives a copy of its argument.
        //
        // Unlike scalar multiplication, there is no "symmetry" 
        // problem here, so I only need one version of 
        // operator+.
        //
        // You can do an internet search to learn more about 
        // the "hidden friend" idiom used here. I like the 
        // video by Dan Saks:
        // https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=POa_V15je8Y
        return a += b;
    }
    std::string to_string() const
    {
        return std::format("[{}, {}, {}]", x(), y(), z());
    }
    friend std::ostream& operator<< (
        std::ostream& ost,
        Vector3D const& v)
    {
        // Another hidden friend.
        //
        // Once again, this function must be implemented as 
        // a non-member function, because the left operand 
        // is not a Vector3D object.
        ost << v.to_string();
        return ost;
    }
    value_type& operator[](std::size_t const i) noexcept
    {
        // Trap subscripting errors.
        return v.at(i);
    }
    value_type const& operator[](std::size_t const i) const noexcept
    {
        // Trap subscripting errors.
        return v.at(i);
    }
};
int main()
{
    Vector3D a{ 1, 2, 3 };
    a *= 2;
    auto b = a * 3;
    std::cout
        << "a     : " << a
        << "\nb     : " << b
        << "\nb * 2 : " << b * 2
        << "\n2 * b : " << 2 * b
        << "\na + b : " << a + b
        << "\n\n";
    return 0;
}
// end file: main.cpp
```

Output:

```
a     : [2, 4, 6]
b     : [6, 12, 18]
b * 2 : [12, 24, 36]
2 * b : [12, 24, 36]
a + b : [8, 16, 24]
```

Comment: Thanks for your explanation and suggested alternative :-). it is nice how all overloaded operators now got included in one data structure! One question though regarding the decision making behind choosing to make the vector a class and not struct and having x, y and z as methods? I can see in the constructor that you've defined them as doubles but why not doing so from the start? Is it to do with returning? It is this part under `public:` what mostly I am not familiar with. Actually no, it's when defining an enum and downward. If you can please explain further to me would be much appreciated..

Comment: The easiest way to fix `operator[]` was to use an array to hold the three vector components. Adding functions `x()`, `y()`, and `z()` was just a bit of syntatic sugar, designed to let you use the natural x-y-z notation. With that structure in place, there was no need to make the array public, so I switched from `struct` to `class`, and made the array private.

Comment: The `enum` is just a trick way for declaring typed constants. The enumeration constants will be implicitly converted to type `std::size_t` when they are used in expressions where an integral value is expected..

Comment: @pk6x, You may want to read through the code again. I have added more detail to some of the explanations.